# Deploying multiple build variants at a time - Android studio gradle

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I recently discovered this awesome feature about gradle productFlavors. I currently have 3 variants (staging, sandbox and production) and I can deploy one of the variants at a time using build variant panel.

Is there a way I can deploy all variants at a time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes,
In Android Studio, open the "Gradle Tasks" tab, which is usually on the right. You will see many tasks that start with 'assemble', double click on one of those.

For example, double clicking on 'assembleRelease' will create all your release apks.

From the docs:

> Building and Tasks
>
> We previously saw that each Build Type creates its own assemble
>   task, but that Build Variants are a combination of Build Type and
>   Product Flavor.
>
> When Product Flavors are used, more assemble-type tasks are created.
>   These are:
>
> 1) assemble[Variant Name]
>
> 2) assemble[Build Type Name]
>
> 3) assemble[Product Flavor Name]
>
> 1) allows directly building a single variant. For instance
>   assembleFlavor1Debug.
>
> 2) allows building all APKs for a given Build Type. For instance
>   assembleDebug will build both Flavor1Debug and Flavor2Debug variants.
>
> 3) allows building all APKs for a given flavor. For instance
>   assembleFlavor1 will build both Flavor1Debug and Flavor1Release
>   variants.
>
> The task assemble will build all possible variants.

Comment: This does not deploy the variants as the OP requested. This only assembles them (i.e. they are not pushed to a device/emulator)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the names of the gradle tasks that install your variants you can run this from the root of your project in the terminal:

```
./gradlew install{VariantName1, VariantName2, VariantName3}Debug
```

This assumes you have a module build.gradle file with variants set up according to [the guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants). So something along these lines:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    ...

    flavorDimensions "myFlavorDimension"
    productFlavors {
        VariantName1 {
            ...
        }
        VariantName2 {
            ...
        }
        VariantName3 {
            ...
        }
    }
    
    ...

}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

You can find these gradle task names either in Android Studio in the Gradle Tab (right side of GUI) under you moduleName->Tasks->install

Or you can find them in the terminal with:

```
./gradlew tasks | grep install
```

I'm sure there is some Regex that could grab only the ones of interest programmatically as well, but I'm not a regex buff. If you want to leave a comment with something that would work, I'd be happy to edit and add later.