# Detect the stage of the app (alpha, beta or production)

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, mixpanel

I'm developing an android app using cordova and I wish to use the three given stages to release it gradually:

- Alpha for IT tests
- Beta for partners
- Production for everyone else

However, I'm using mixpanel to track some user inputs. 
Mixpanel requires a token to work and I have 2 of them, one for beta and other for production, it is loaded with `mixpanel.init("token1")` when the app starts.

Currently, I build an apk with no token defined to run in alpha, then I build another one with token1 to run in beta, and later on another apk with token2 to run in prod. It works, but it's a pain.

I wish to use the `promote` option inside the Google Play Developer Console, so I could build one single apk (automated) that gets promoted to beta/prod when needed and knows which stage it is in, so it uses the token accordingly.

Is it possible? If not, is there a better way to make it work?

**TL;DR** Want to know which stage (alpha/beta/prod) the app is running in so it uses a token variable accordingly.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find an optimal solution. What we did was create a hidden menu that only the alpha testers know how to enable and allow them to change the token in runtime. So we always build with production token, but the alphas change it manually before testing. Served our case.

Comment: I've also asked in the androids and cordovas slack channels, in both of them people said there is no way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Was hoping to find a way to keep only the one apk, throughout alpha, beta and prod, by testing the state to manage endpoints.

Comment: @Magda Did you ever find a way to switch over environment at runtime like this? Absolutely laughable that a "reasonable" solution is putting a hidden menu into your app. It should be possible to detect stage at runtime...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help but are you using build.gradle to make different product flavours? You can make it so that it will generate a class with different final constants in each type of build.

So for your prod build, you can do something like this:

```
prod {  
applicationId "zuul.com.android"
buildConfigField 'String', 'HOST', '"http://api.zuul.com"'
buildConfigField 'String', 'FLAVOR', '"prod"'
buildConfigField "boolean", "REPORT_CRASHES", "true"
}
```

and it comes out like this:

```
BuildConfig.HOST  
BuildConfig.FLAVOR  
BuildConfig.REPORT_CRASHES
```

And then you can have one for dev, beta, or whatever.

Check out these links:

http://blog.brainattica.com/how-to-work-with-flavours-on-android/

[Deploying multiple build variants at a time - Android studio gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648470/deploying-multiple-build-variants-at-a-time-android-studio-gradle)

Comment: But with flavors I'll still need to build 3 of them and send to the store individually for each of the stages, right? I want to use the promote option.