# Detecting current app channel/stream/track/stage on a cordova application

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I was wondering : is it something possible to detect current track used on a running Cordova Application ?

By track, I mean if we're on the alpha/beta/production track on Android, or on TestFlight / Prod on iOS.
*(the semantic is not clear around this, we can talk about stage / channel / stream / track depending on the platform/docs)*

My need would be to detect programmatically this distribution channel from within the app in order to adapt some of my application behaviour based on it (typically, I would like to have this information in my analytics, and use separate API keys for some of my cloud services depending on it)

*Side note : I don't want to create different flavour of my app based on current distribution channel. I use versions promotion in Google/Apple stores to promote versions from a lower to a higher (more stable) distribution channel, and don't want to create separate artefacts per channel (I already have a long release process, and would like to avoid releasing a lot more artefacts than what I am producing already)*

Comment: It looks like it was something impossible in Android 4y ago (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41246798/detect-the-stage-of-the-app-alpha-beta-or-production) but I would like to extend the area of the question to (at least) iOS Apps as well